# Need help to understand how this function composition works

Tags: haskell, function-composition

I can understand this line of code without problem

```
let f s = filter (isDigit.head) (groupBy (on (==) isDigit) s)
```

when I call `f "123abc345"`, it returns `["123", "345"]`

But I am having a hard time understanding why the following line of code is the same

```
let g = filter (isDigit.head) . groupBy (on (==) isDigit)
```

How does this composition work? Thank you very much!

Comment: one is just the "pointfree" version of the other. Use the definition of composition: `(f . g) x = f (g x)` and look at what happens when you apply `g` to `s`.

Comment: I would write `isDigit . head` instead of `isDigit.head`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your code, for reference:

```
let f s = filter (isDigit.head)  (groupBy (on (==) isDigit) s)
let g   = filter (isDigit.head) . groupBy (on (==) isDigit)
```

(I've formatted it slightly to emphasize the similarities.)

To help us a bit, let's now define some synonyms for the functions in your definitions:

```
let whereFirstIsDigit = filter (isDigit.head)
let groupByDigit      = groupBy (on (==) isDigit))
```

Now we can rewrite the original functions as follows:

```
let f s = whereFirstIsDigit  (groupByDigit s)
let g   = whereFirstIsDigit . groupByDigit
```

Now let's look at what's happening here. `f` takes `s`, feeds it to `groupByDigit`, and then feeds the result of that to `whereFirstIsDigit`. But the function composition of (say) `x . y` is defined to be the function which feeds its input to `y`, and then feeds that result to `x`! So the two functions are the same.

Comment: Thank you. I got confused by the precedence rules. I thought (isDigit.head) . groupBy (on (==) isDigit) was the predicate. Now I got it.

Comment: @klabe That's correct. In general, function application binds tighter than any operator, so e.g. `f a ++ g b` is the same as `(f a) ++ (g b)`.

Answer (score 2):

Function composition operator `.` is defined like this:

```
(.) f g = \x -> f (g x)
```

Or, the same thing in infix form:

```
f . g = \x -> f (g x)
```

In English this can be expressed like this: *composition of two functions `f` and `g` is another function that takes an argument `x`, passes it to function `g`, and then passes the return value of `g` to function `f`*

If you look at your first snippet:

```
let f s = filter (isDigit.head) (groupBy (on (==) isDigit) s)
```

If your squint hard enough, you can see that it's a function that takes argument `s`, passes it to function `groupBy (on (==) isDigit)`, and then passes the return value to function `filter (isDigit.head)`

Which, according to my explanation above, can be expressed as a composition of two functions - `filter (isDigit.head)` and `groupBy (on (==) isDigit)`, which is what your second snippet is.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I got confused by the precedence rules. I am sorry I can only accept one answer.